# Show a notification window then fade it out, but pause the animation on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm normally an ASP.NET programmer, so I don't have much experience with WPF. I'm trying to create a notification window that opens on the screen in response to some server side event. I want it to behave similarly to the notifications given by Microsoft Outlook. The window should show for 5 seconds, then begin fading out which should last for 5 seconds, at which point the window should close. If the user mouses over the window, the windowTimer or the fade out animation should pause depending on how much time has elapsed. This works fine in the first 5 seconds of execution. However, once the fade out animation starts, it doesn't pause by mousing over. My question is: Why isn't my code pausing the animation when the mouse enters?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Timer windowTimer; //System.Timers.Timer
    AnimationClock clock;
    bool fadingOut = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContentRendered(e);
        windowTimer = new Timer(5000);//5 seconds
        windowTimer.Start();
        windowTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(windowTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        if (!fadingOut)
        {
            windowTimer.Stop();
        }
        if (clock != null)
        {
            clock.Controller.Pause();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        if (!fadingOut)
        {
            windowTimer.Start();
        }
        if (clock != null)
        {
            clock.Controller.Resume();
        }
    }

    private void windowTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        windowTimer.Elapsed -= windowTimer_Elapsed;
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(() => BeginFadeout()));
    }

    private void BeginFadeout()
    {
        windowTimer.Stop();
        fadingOut = true;
        DoubleAnimation fadeoutanim = new DoubleAnimation(0,
            (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        fadeoutanim.Completed += (s, _) => this.Close();
        clock = fadeoutanim.CreateClock();
        this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeoutanim);
    }
}
```

Comment: Open blend. Create your notification window. Create a storyboard animation that fades it out.  Then in your C# code play and pause your storyboard based on when you want it to fade out or not

Comment: Is there a way to do that without using Blend? I'm in Visual Studio 2010 Pro. Also, can you explain why my current code isn't pausing the animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your code working you could just replace `this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeoutanim);` with `this.ApplyAnimationClock(OpacityProperty, clock);`, otherwise the clock you get is not the one that controls the animation.

Also, your code will throw exception if the mouse is over the window when it starts, you should ensure that windowTimer is not null before starting / stopping it.

But using a storyboard is clearly a cleaner solution.

Instead of recreating your own notification, you should have a look at [this](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) library, which is available from NuGet and has a good [howto](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon#balloons).

Comment: Thanks, your code worked more like I expected. I will definitely check the library out too, as I was intending to turn this into an application that sits in the system tray.

Answer (score 4):

So the easiest way to do this is with storyboards. Since blend is a very easy tool to use and makes quick work of this I will use this as the example. You can also of course create the storyboard by hand.

Step 1: Create your control

[image]

Step2: Create your storyboard by clicking the little plus symbol on the left. Name it something meaningful. You will note that the UI element you have selected in the list on the left will be the one that the storyboard is applied to.

[image]

Step 3: On the left set the keyframe. This is how long the animation will take to execute and where it will execute what you tell it to. Make sure to set the keyframe FIRST then set the properties.

[image]

Step 4: Finally go into visual studio and execute your storyboard. 
In this example the storyboard resides in the static resources. So I pull it out of the static resources and tell it to either begin or stop (which returns it to the start which in this case is opacity 1)

[image]

If you still want to do it by hand then add this to your notification window XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeOutAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

I know a quick copy and paste seems faster but learning to use Blend will save you a ton of UI heart ache in the future.

Comment: Well the obvious answer is that your original code is very complicated and could be causing bugs for a number of reasons. It's not in line with WPF common architecture and should be avoided. I accomplished the proper effect with 11 lines of code in total that took you 5x as much. This is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: +1 for making me aware of the Storyboard feature ;-)

Comment: Your code isn't working because you are taking the incorrect approach to it. WPF Doesn't animate objects like winforms. You don't need to have a timer. Furthermore you shouldn't be dynamically building it unless there is no other option. That bogs down cycles. In WPF you use Storyboard animations and you do it in XAML. That is the power of WPF. That is why I have not answered your question but instead I provided you with the correct way to do what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't care if you accept the answer or not. At this point it serves as a record and example of the correct way to do this for future people having a similar issue. Even the answer you accepted clearly says its the correct way to do it. Good luck with your code.

Comment: I told you why your code wasn't working. It was wrong.

Comment: @mason Comments are not for extended discussions. I told you why this was posted. The community clearly agrees this is a good approach otherwise it would have been downvoted. Please stop wasting everyone's time on here.